# Какой сделать вывод о взаимосвязях в данных по графику heatmap?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

Сделан график heatmap

[image: heatmap]

Какой вывод можно сделать о взаимосвязях в данных? Датасет
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YzGDML_wBZSJTGip3yZ1uk6HTTCSg_nD/view?usp=sharing 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('datatraining.txt', sep=r',', engine='python', header=None, names = ['id', 'date','Temperature','Humidity','Light','CO2','HumidityRatio','Occupancy'])
df = df.drop([0])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.drop('date', axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
def scale(df):
    return (df - df.mean()) / df.std()
df.Temperature = scale(df.Temperature)
df.Humidity = scale(df.Humidity)
df.Light = scale(df.Light)
df.CO2 = scale(df.CO2)
df.HumidityRatio = scale(df.HumidityRatio)


corr = df.drop(columns=["id"]).corr().abs()      
np.fill_diagonal(corr.values, 0)

sns.heatmap(corr, cmap="YlOrBr", annot=True)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я думаю стоит задать четыре отдельных вопроса...

Comment: Дословный вопрос в задании : "Принимая во внимание все построенные выше графики, сделайте вывод о взаимосвязях в данных (напишите несколько предложений о том, что вы заметили)"

Comment: я имел ввиду 4 отдельных SO вопроса

Comment: Переделала на 4 вопроса

Comment: @MaxU если данные связанны, то надо бы смотреть их вместе...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1026650/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-pairplot

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1026652/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-violinplot

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1026651/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-boxplot

Comment: За что отвечает тип графика heatmap?

Comment: @eri, не думаю что это будет полезным кому-нибудь кроме автора вопроса...

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/ods/blog/323210/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`heatmap` или "температурная карта" наглядно демонстрирует клетки матрицы с большими / меньшими значениями.

Например в вашем случае вы похоже пытаетесь визуализировать величину корреляции столбцов DataFrame. Я бы в данном случае использовал значения корреляции по модулю и обнулил бы диагональные элементы - так будет лучше видно ячейки с большей корреляцией.

Пример:

```
corr = df.drop(columns=["id", "date"]).corr().abs()      
np.fill_diagonal(corr.values, 0)

sns.heatmap(corr, cmap="YlOrBr", annot=True)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**Пояснение:** наиболее темные ячейки наглядно демонстрируют пары столбцов с наибольшей корреляцией. Чем темнее ячейка - тем больше корреляция соответствующих столбцов.

---

Таблица корреляции по Пирсону (без изменений):

```
In [28]: corr
Out[28]:
               Temperature  Humidity     Light       CO2  HumidityRatio  Occupancy
Temperature       1.000000 -0.141759  0.649942  0.559894       0.151762   0.538220
Humidity         -0.141759  1.000000  0.037828  0.439023       0.955198   0.132964
Light             0.649942  0.037828  1.000000  0.664022       0.230420   0.907352
CO2               0.559894  0.439023  0.664022  1.000000       0.626556   0.712235
HumidityRatio     0.151762  0.955198  0.230420  0.626556       1.000000   0.300282
Occupancy         0.538220  0.132964  0.907352  0.712235       0.300282   1.000000
```

Видоизмененная таблица корреляции (с обнуленной главной диагональю и со значениями по модулю):

```
In [32]: corr
Out[32]:
               Temperature  Humidity     Light       CO2  HumidityRatio  Occupancy
Temperature       0.000000  0.141759  0.649942  0.559894       0.151762   0.538220
Humidity          0.141759  0.000000  0.037828  0.439023       0.955198   0.132964
Light             0.649942  0.037828  0.000000  0.664022       0.230420   0.907352
CO2               0.559894  0.439023  0.664022  0.000000       0.626556   0.712235
HumidityRatio     0.151762  0.955198  0.230420  0.626556       0.000000   0.300282
Occupancy         0.538220  0.132964  0.907352  0.712235       0.300282   0.000000
```

Comment: Heatmap позволяет посмотреть на распределение какого-то численного признака по двум категориальным. 
HumidityRatio и Humidity дают самый высокий численный показатель.
А вот Humidity и Temperature - самый низкий.

Comment: У меня опять срезанная получилась таблица

Comment: `plt.figure(figsize=(7,6))
corr = df.drop(columns=["id"]).corr().abs()      
np.fill_diagonal(corr.values, 0)
ax = sns.heatmap(corr, cmap=sns.color_palette("YlOrBr", 1000), vmin=-1, center=0, annot=True)
i, k = ax.get_ylim()
ax.set_ylim(i+0.5, k-0.5)` Так ровно

Comment: @svil, не понимаю что вы хотели сказать данным комментарием...

Comment: Не получаетс я у меня применить plt.tight_layout() чтобы ровная таблица получилась

Comment: Но об этом не в этом вопросе надо было написать