# Какой сделать вывод о взаимосвязях в данных по графику pairplot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, статистика

Сделан график  pairplot https://drive.google.com/file/d/12BW4i_OEXqV1j0oVSGIWm6HFaUfZUOz0/view?usp=sharing
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какой вывод можно сделать о взаимосвязях в данных?
Датасет https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YzGDML_wBZSJTGip3yZ1uk6HTTCSg_nD/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pairplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) показывает попарные (пары столбцов) отношения значений в `DataFrame`. По диагонали показывается либо гистограмма значений соответствующего столбца либо [плотность вероятности распределения значений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) данного столбца.

Пример:

```
sns.pairplot(df.drop(columns=["id", "date"]), hue="Occupancy")
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]