# Какой сделать вывод о взаимосвязях в данных по графику boxplot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, статистика

Сделан график boxplot

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kXKpIYCL8Wz3u1Cr092LX7T-lgzgkfmg/view?usp=sharing
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какой вывод можно сделать о взаимосвязях в данных? Датасет
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kXKpIYCL8Wz3u1Cr092LX7T-lgzgkfmg/view?usp=sharing
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`boxplot` или "ящик с усами"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) - график, использующийся в описательной статистике, компактно изображающий одномерное распределение вероятностей.

Такой вид диаграммы в удобной форме показывает медиану (или, если нужно, среднее), нижний и верхний квартили, минимальное и максимальное значение выборки и выбросы. Несколько таких ящиков можно нарисовать бок о бок, чтобы визуально сравнивать одно распределение с другим; их можно располагать как горизонтально, так и вертикально. Расстояния между различными частями ящика позволяют определить степень разброса (дисперсии) и асимметрии данных и выявить выбросы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]