# Какой сделать вывод о взаимосвязях в данных по графику violinplot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, статистика

Сделан график violinplot
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wmkH67q_qnfDnvQeU_5uDZ0M8RT8f9Ht/view?usp=sharing
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какой вывод можно сделать о взаимосвязях в данных? Датасет https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YzGDML_wBZSJTGip3yZ1uk6HTTCSg_nD/view?usp=sharing
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Violinplot`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin_plot) - расширенная версия [`boxplot`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1026651/), который в дополнение к `boxplot` также показывает [плотность вероятности распределения значений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) (см. также - [Ядерная оценка плотности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)).